# Sencha Touch Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to load a resource with sencha touch on rails but i get the following error:

```
Started OPTIONS "/menu_items.json?_dc=1322512349038&limit=25&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-28 18:32:29 -0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/menu_items.json"):
```

My store code:

```
new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'MenuItem',
                sorters: 'name',
                getGroupString: function(r){
                    return r.get('name')[0] || "";
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'rest',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/menu_items',
                    format: 'json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'menu_item'
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    load: { fn: this.initializeData, scope: this }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Rails code looks something like below, then the problem is probably the `OPTIONS` method that is used - the `index` action only responds to `GET`. Do you know why `OPTIONS` is used here? I can't find this in the Sencha Touch docu for the data store..

```
# config/routes.rb
# ...
resources :menu_items

# app/controllers/menu_items_controller.rb
class MenuItemsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @menu_items = MenuItem.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @menu_items }
      end
    end
end
```

BTW: from what I see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest), you should maybe move the proxy code into the `MenuItem` model.

Answer (score 0):

The `OPTION` request is part of the **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** protocol. Check [this valuable post](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428) about it. You can use the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem to easily configure it.